# How to number centered section titles?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am trying to create sections that are centered, but still with numbering.
When I center the section titles (like below), the numbering disappears.

`\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt,cleanfoot]{asme2ej}
 \usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
 \titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}`

Any ideas on how I can do this? 
What I want is of the format in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track for standard classes: use

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
```

(In my opinion, `1em` is too much). With `asme2ej`, I don't know, as it is not part of the main distributions.